# How to reshape a scalar funcction to a scalar function on a grid

Tags: numpy, grid

My question is more of a general question about how np.meshgrid is organized to understand it better. So I have a set of 3d points and for each point I have a scalar value associated with it. So for this function is shaped as n x 1, however now I want to reshape this function with the same values, to a np.meshgrid this means to make it to a 3D numpy array. However I don't understand how can I begin to do that this, since I don't know how it supposed to look like. Do you know how I can do this and the reasoning behind it?

Thank you I'm really new to np.meshgrids and I still can't comprehend it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain it in 2D (going to 3D if you understand it is quite easy).

Just imagine you have a section from the two dimensional plane. Lets say its a square with 5 in length and width. But the coordinates for x are in [10,15]
and for y in [15,20], respectively.

Now you want to evaluate a function on this section (lets say with a resolution of 0.5). Numpys **meshgrid** now gives you two matrices in which the x and y coordinates for each "pixel" (0.5 x 0.5 area) are saved.

In some code this looks like:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10,15,.5)
y = np.arange(15,20,.5)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y, indexing = 'ij')
```

our area is dived into 10x10 pixels and therefore we expect the shapes to be:

```py
xx.shape
>>> (10, 10)
```

```py
yy.shape
>>> (10, 10)
```

looking at `xx`:

```py
array([[10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. , 10. ],
       [10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5],
       [11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. , 11. ],
       [11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5],
       [12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. , 12. ],
       [12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5],
       [13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. , 13. ],
       [13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5],
       [14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. , 14. ],
       [14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5]])
```

and `yy`:

```py
array([[15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5],
       [15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5]])
```

so to the the coordinates for the 4 pixel into x and 5 pixel into y direction you can just get:

```py
x_coord = xx[4,5]
y_coord = yy[4,5]
```

```py
x_coord
>>> 12.0
```

```py
y_coord
>>> 17.5
```

If you want in 3D you have three cubes instead of two matrices that's basically it.

Now if you want to evaluate a function on this lets say:

```py
def fun(x,y):
    return np.sin(x)*np.cos(y)
```

you can just use `xx` and `yy` like:

```py
zz = fun(xx,yy)
zz.shape
```

```py
>>> (10, 10)
```

and it looks like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contourf(xx,yy,zz)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that gave me a lot of clarity on the matter. if I may ask you another question. I have a scalar function Fun = [0,0,1,0....,0] per each point in 3D. Now with help of your explanation I was able to transform the Fun to a grid function like this: 
```python
arr = np.zeros((Fun.shape[0],Fun.shape[0]),np.float32)
for i in range(0,Fun.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,Fun.shape[0]):
        arr[i][j] = Fun[i]
val= []
val.append(arr)
val.append(arr)
val.append(arr)

isovalue = np.asarray(val)
```
Is this would create it correctly?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you try to do there... People here only/mostly can help with **working** examples.

Comment: try to condense it to a very small example and create a new post with a spesific question

Comment: Sorry you are right I talked to general. So for example I have a scalar function that is Fun = [0,1,1,0]  if I want to transform it two grid function in 3D i have to make an array of shape (4,4,4), I should create it by doing a loop like:
```Python 
arr = np.zeros((Fun.shape[0],Fun.shape[0],Fun.shape[0]),np.float32)
for i in range(0,Fun.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,Fun.shape[0]):
        for k in range(0,Fun.shape[0]):
            arr[i][j][k] = Fun[i]
```

Comment: whats the question now? if it is correct? i have no idea what you try to do there so i dont know... (btw Fun is a **list** not a function)