# How to deform/scale a 3 dimensional numpy array in one dimension?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scale, scaletransform

I would like to deform/scale a **three dimensional numpy array** in one dimension. I will visualize my problem in 2D:

I have the original image, which is a 2D numpy array:

[image]

Then I want to deform/scale it for some factor in dimension 0, or horizontal dimension:

[image]

For [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) images, there are a lot of solutions, for example in [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.affine), but what if I have a numpy array of shapes (w, h, d) = (288, 288, 468)? I would like to upsample the width with a factor of 1.04, for example, to (299, 288, 468). Each cell contains a normalized number between 0 and 1.

I am not sure, if I am simply not looking for the correct vocabulary, if I try to search online. So also correcting my question would help. Or tell me the mathematical background of this problem, then I can write the code on my own.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is what should happen with the values you are adding? For example if you want "stretch" the array of the shape (100,200,50) to (100,300,50) what should the values in between (there are more number now) look like? Probably you are looking for interpolation and therefore you could use one of the many library for instance the scipy one.

Comment: Good question, I think I have to try different possibilities. I need this for medical data, namely PET/PSMA. I don't know what keeps the data realistic.

Comment: Yeah thats a very critical application... If its only about visual inspection I guess bicubic interpolation could work for you (as long as you just change the dimensions slightly like 20% of original size or so). Can you give us example data that is similar to what you are working with?

Comment: Example data is not easy to get. Maybe something like [this](https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/Head-Neck-PET-CT). The scaling will be in a realistic proportion, indeed. Do you know any libraries for 3D interpolation?

Comment: Whats in the 3 channel? For example if you have a RGB image you would have a array with the shape (w,h,3) with w and h the width and height respectively. Now there is not really a reason to threat is as a 3d interpolation because the colors don't have to be "connected" they are more or less independent. So you would treat it as 3x a 2D interpolation. But ofc in medical imagery there could be other information hidden in the channels so that would be a relevant information (if you allready know the shape of the data).

Comment: (w, h, d) = (288, 288, 468) would be the shape of one example. Now I would like to upsample the width with a factor of 1.04, for example, to (299, 288, 468). Each cell contains a normalized number between 0 and 1. I will add that to my initial question.

Comment: is it a 3d Image or whats the meaning of the third dimension?

Comment: The third dimension are slices through the body. [This](https://sites.google.com/site/linhvtlam2/fl7_ctslices.jpg) image might give you an idea. But it can be treated as a 3D image, yes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I will put my answer bellow maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is as easy as using the `torch.nn.functional.interpolate` functional from [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate) and choosing 'trilinear' as interpolation mode:

```
import torch

PET = torch.tensor(data)

print("Old shape = {}".format(PET.shape))

scale_factor_x = 1.4

# Scaling.
PET = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(PET.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0),\
 scale_factor=(scale_factor_x, 1, 1), mode='trilinear').squeeze().squeeze()

print("New shape = {}".format(PET.shape))
```

output:

```
>>> Old shape = torch.Size([288, 288, 468])
>>> New shape = torch.Size([403, 288, 468])
```

I verified the results by looking at the data, but I can't show them here due to data privacy. Sorry!

Comment: Excellent and clean solution. This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the array along the specific axis a number of times equal to `ceil(factor)` where `factor > 1` and then evenly space indices on the stretched dimension to select `int(factor * old_length)` elements. This does not perform any kind of interpolation but just repeats some of the elements:

```
import math

import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import imread

img = imread('/tmp/example.png')
print(img.shape)  # (512, 512)

axis = 1
factor = 1.25

stretched = np.repeat(img, math.ceil(factor), axis=axis)
print(stretched.shape)  # (512, 1024)

indices = np.linspace(0, stretched.shape[axis] - 1, int(img.shape[axis] * factor))
indices = np.rint(indices).astype(int)

result = np.take(stretched, indices, axis=axis)
print(result.shape)  # (512, 640)

cv2.imwrite('/tmp/stretched.png', result)
```

This is the result (left is original `example.png` and right is `stretched.png`):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for linear up-sampling a 3D Image with `scipy.interpolate`, hope it helps.

(I worked quite a lot with `np.meshgrid` here, if you not familiar with it i recently explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095991/how-to-reshape-a-scalar-funcction-to-a-scalar-function-on-a-grid/57096739#57096739))

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

# should be 1.3.0
print(scipy.__version__)

# =============================================================================
# producing a test image "image3D"
# =============================================================================

def some_function(x,y,z):
    # output is a 3D Gaussian with some periodic modification
    # its only for testing so this part is not impotent
    out = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)*np.cos(np.pi*y)*np.cos(4*np.pi*z)*np.exp(-(x**2+y**2+z**2))
    return out


# define a grid to evaluate the function on.
# the dimension of the 3D-Image will be (20,20,20)
N = 20
x = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
z = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,indexing ='ij')

image3D = some_function(xx,yy,zz)

# =============================================================================
# plot the testimage "image3D"
# you will see 5 images that corresponds to the slicing of the 
# z-axis similar to your example picture_
# https://sites.google.com/site/linhvtlam2/fl7_ctslices.jpg
# =============================================================================

def plot_slices(image_3d):
    f, loax = plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(15,5))    
    loax = loax.flatten()
    for ii,i in enumerate([8,9,10,11,12]):
        loax[ii].imshow(image_3d[:,:,i],vmin=image_3d.min(),vmax=image_3d.max())
    plt.show()

plot_slices(image3D)

# =============================================================================
# interpolate the image
# =============================================================================

interpolation_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), image3D, method = 'linear')

# =============================================================================
# evaluate at new grid
# =============================================================================

# create the new grid that you want
x_new = np.linspace(-1,1,30)
y_new = np.linspace(-1,1,40)
z_new = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
xx_new, yy_new, zz_new = np.meshgrid(x_new,y_new,z_new,indexing ='ij')

# change the order of the points to match the input shape of the interpolation
# function. That's a bit messy but i couldn't figure out a way around that
evaluation_points = np.rollaxis(np.array([xx_new,yy_new,zz_new]),0,4)

interpolated = interpolation_function(evaluation_points)

plot_slices(interpolated)
```

The original `(20,20,20)` dimensional 3D Image:

[image]

And the upsampeled `(30,40,20)` dimensional 3D Image:

[image]